# Crash with Missing cell for newly visible row when updating UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am experiencing a crash when I delete a row.

```
// Updating my data model 
....
// apply the updates
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPathsToDelete, with: .automatic)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Steps to reproduce
- Add rows
- Delete rows, specifically making sure there's some rows outside the current screen (that will then be in screen when the deletion is successful
- Repeat until crash occurs

It doesn't always happen so my best guess is that it will happen only when the cells it's trying to load get recycled

This is in 10.0 simulator with Xcode 8.0

```
  *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:],
 /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3599.6/UITableView.m:3149
 Missing cell for newly visible row 2
 (null)
```

code for cellForRowAt

```
if isMultipe{
   let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: DetailsTableViewCell.defaultIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! DetailsTableViewCell
return cell
    } else {
let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: DetailsMultipleTableViewCell.defaultIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! DetailsMultipleTableViewCell
   return cell
}
```

the same bug reported here : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/49676

Comment: How do you dequeue your cell? Can you show your code in `cellForRow...`  ?

Comment: @Hoa question updated

Comment: So you registered the .xib to the cell class and dequeue it when need. There is maybe a problem with iOS10, but try to check if your cell is `nil`or not after the `dequeueReusableCell` line.

Comment: @Hoa the cells are not nil because it would crash with the force unwrap I guess

Comment: your are removing object from array and adding new object in array so you need to reloadTableview

Comment: @MuhammadNoman actually  `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` will reload the table with animation

Comment: Are you using `estimatedSectionHeaderHeight `?

Comment: @emrekyv yes and for cells also

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and I found out that `UITableView` has serious problems with animating insert/update/delete rows when section headers are variable height. Just convert the height to some constant and try it again.

This actually means deleting `estimatedSectionHeaderHeight`.

Comment: But `heightForHeaderInSection` is ok to have? Or do you have to delete that too.

Comment: @tettoffensive `heightForHeaderInSection` is fine to have.

Comment: looks that even without `estimatedSectionHeaderHeight` you can still get `missing cell for newly visible row ##`

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was crashing when cells have used autolayout for calculating it's height. So, the only guaranteed solution is use manual calculating heights. (what is actually sad..)

Comment: That's what I have end up doing, but there should be an explanation

Comment: Did you use autolayout for the cell itself? I already turned off autolayout for calculating heights, but I'm still using autolayout for positioning the subviews. I'm still getting the error though.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had this issue just for inserting the first row to an empty section, so I tried to fix it like this:

```
self.array.append(item)
if self.array.count > 1 {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.insertRows(at: indexPathes, with: .top)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
} else {
    self.tableView.reloadSections([1], with: .fade)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem happened to me when I had cells with different sizes. My code:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

During moving/inserting/deleting, app was crashing with `"Missing cell for newly visible row"` message. So I removed this line:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150
```

and implement delegate method in which returned separate estimated height for each row.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {}
```

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Remove indexPath in tableView.dequeueReusableCell

```
if isMultipe{
   let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: DetailsTableViewCell.defaultIdentifier) as! DetailsTableViewCell
return cell
    } else {
let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: DetailsMultipleTableViewCell.defaultIdentifier) as! DetailsMultipleTableViewCell
   return cell
}
```

Comment: I already have dequeueReusableCell without indexPath and still hitting this error.....

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

emrekyv suggested to delete `estimatedSectionHeaderHeight` but I have a table with one seaction and no header and no footer.

Expanding his idea and setting `estimatedRowHeight` to 0 (= not automatic) fixed the problem.

So the rule is:

Do not estimate any height when updating a UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happened when I forgot to call `super.prepareForReuse()` in my custom subclass.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse:

> If you override this method, you must be sure to invoke the superclass
>   implementation.