# UITableView Missing cell for newly visible row NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, uikit

I've been getting this issue with my app and not sure what went wrong.
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Missing cell for newly visible row 78

Here's the stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x191bbefd8 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x190620538 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x191bbeeac +[NSException raise:format:]
3  Foundation                     0x192656710 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
4  UIKit                          0x198022b3c __46-[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:]_block_invoke.1049
5  UIKit                          0x197d234b8 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:]
6  UIKit                          0x197d39bac +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:]
7  UIKit                          0x197ee8770 -[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:]
8  UIKit                          0x197eccfbc -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:]
9  MyApp                      0x1000ed518 -[UICommentsTableViewController insertNewComment:atLocation:] (UICommentsTableViewController.m:1228)
10 MyApp                      0x1000e99e8 -[UICommentsTableViewController onCommentsReceivedWithMessage:] (UICommentsTableViewController.m:881)
11 MyApp                      0x1000e9094 -[UICommentsTableViewController processWSMessage:] (UICommentsTableViewController.m:803)
12 MyApp                      0x1000e8f84 -[UICommentsTableViewController webSocket:didReceiveMessage:] (UICommentsTableViewController.m:788)
13 MyApp                      0x10009ea30 __30-[SRWebSocket _handleMessage:]_block_invoke (SRWebSocket.m:837)
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x190a769e0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x190a769a0 _dispatch_client_callout
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x190a7b5e8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
17 CoreFoundation                 0x191b6d0c0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
18 CoreFoundation                 0x191b6acdc __CFRunLoopRun
19 CoreFoundation                 0x191a9ad94 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
20 GraphicsServices               0x193504074 GSEventRunModal
21 UIKit                          0x197d53130 UIApplicationMain
22 MyApp                      0x10011ba40 main (main.m:7)
23 libdyld.dylib                  0x190aa959c start
```

The error happens here:

```
- (void)insertNewComment:(NSIndexSet *)indexSet atLocation:(NSInteger)location{

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    NSMutableArray *indexArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    if (!indexSet) {
        [indexArray addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:location inSection:0]];
    } else {
        [indexSet enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop ) {
            [indexArray addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];
        }];
    }

    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}
```

I'm using AutoLayout for the cell, but I calculated the height manually and cache them according to their device orientation.

height calculator:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    Comment* comment = self.comments[indexPath.row];

    CGFloat cellHeight = [self getHeightForLayoutMode:self.screenMode forCommentID:comment.commentID];

    if(cellHeight > 0) {

        return cellHeight;
    }


    if([comment isType2]) {
        [self setHeightForLayoutMode:self.screenMode forCommentID:comment.commentID height:106];
        return 106;
    }

    CGFloat width = tableView.bounds.size.width - 100;

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;


    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFont" size:11.0f], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle};

    CGRect rect = [comment.message boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                                options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                             attributes:attributes
                                                context:nil];

    CGFloat height = 31+ceilf(rect.size.height);

    [self setHeightForLayoutMode:self.streamViewController.screenMode forCommentID:comment.commentID height:height];

    return height;
}
```

Someone had an issue like this ([Crash with Missing cell for newly visible row when updating UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358487/crash-with-missing-cell-for-newly-visible-row-when-updating-uitableview)), and they just removed estimatedSectionHeaderHeight, but I don't have estimatedSectionHeaderHeight on my code.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the number of sections is out of range when inserting the value. It's not a height issue.

Comment: hmm that's weird because I only have 1 section.
[indexArray addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:location inSection:0]];

Comment: Also, I put a log before the crash and this is what I see:  
begin insertNewComment location is: 773, comment count is 774
so the self.comments.count is 774, and I'm inserting at the index 773. In addition, though the crashes happens on all devices, most of the crash (85%) occurs within iPhone 5, 5s, SE.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the cause of the problem.

Within my view controller, I have a textview, which will trigger the keyboard to show. I had the UITableView pinned to the bottom. I set it to scrollToBottom on keyboardWillShow & adjust the inset when the textview height changes. Once the keyboard show, the tableview was barely visible (especially on iPhone 5).

Now the fix is I pinned the tableview's bottom to the top of the textview, keeping the same height & visibility of the tableview, and I don't need the scrollToBottom & adjusting inset anymore, because the autolayout takes care of it. Hope it helps someone!

Cheers.